# How to remove scrollview sidebar swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am creating a swiping controller from collection views in my app, but one problem I am having is I am not able to get rid of the thin rectangle that appears whenever I swipe from one collection view cell to the next. The rectangle I am talking about also appears whenever you are scrolling in a scrollview. I am not sure what the proper terminology for this is however I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using StoryBoard uncheck `Show Horizantal Indicator` and `Show Vertical Indicator`

[image]

And in code you can do

```
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false    
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Comment: please upvote if it resolves the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
myCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false    
myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Those properties are inherited of `UIScrollView`